# opencart's shopping cart does not have an inbuilt "alt" tag editor. Will the .jpg file name be adequate enough for search engine optimization?

Tags: html, seo, filenames, alt

Are jpeg file names that are used instead of alt tags a viable way for image SEO? For instance, would placing keywords within the filename like this:

keyword_keyword_keyword-keyword_keyword_keyword.jpg

be just as useful for search engine spiders to index the images as using alt tags? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Pendantic preamble: no such thing as an ALT '*tag*' - they are '*attributes*' of the `IMG` tag.

Now, to your question:

- No, keywords in the filename are not *just as useful* for search spiders, but they **do help**.
- ALT attributes are much more a stronger interpretive signal
- Use hyphens to separate words in the filename to help parsing

More helpful reading (with linked references): http://www.seosmarty.com/image-seo/